# Can't upload wordpress plugin. File size too large

Tags: php, wordpress

When I tried to upload a plugin to my wordpress site (memberpress) I get "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini." error. When I look under add new media it says my maximum file size upload is 25MB. The plugin I'm trying to install is 2.2MB. I have tried editing the php.ini and php5.ini files but it hasn't let me upload the plugin and the max file size hasn't changed under the upload new media section.

Comment: You don't upload WordPress plugins into the media gallery

Answer (score -1):

As it doesn't seem that you are able to edit your *php.ini* file to increase the max allowed upload size, you need to work around this by uploading your plugin to the plugins folder under your WordPress root via ftp.

Answer (score -1):

Also check the post_max_size in php.ini, set it higher. 
Otherwise, check the permission on parent folder, in this case the plugin folder.